# Get By locator from WebElement proxy

Tags: java, selenium, appium

Is there a way to get the By locator used in the failed attempt to find a WebElement in Java? What

I'm trying to do is, at the point where I catch the `NoSuchElementException`, look at By locator and change it before I attempt to find element again (changing from id to xpath). I'm using the page factory pattern and `@FindBy(id=xxx)` - I understand that before WebElement is found that it's a proxy Object I would be working with.
From debug views in Eclipse at breakpoints after element not found,  I can see the By locator information but in code I can't extract it.

Comment: what do you mean by changing the by locator, that's a really silly approach. it won't work. 
Rather than what's not working can you explain what  you try to achieve, your actual problem.

Comment: I think he tries to re-try finding the element when he gets a NoSuchElementException..MikeG please read about implicit/explict wait if the element is not there after some time, well it is NOT there!

Comment: The reasoning for this is that we have existing selenium web automation which uses ids and xpaths to find all elements. We are reusing this code (tests, pages and utils) for our mobile client (using Appium) as client was created using Ionic Framework and so is essentially the web client wrapped in mobile app. However, there are certain issues with our Ionic framework and webviews that means I need to use xpath only to find elements. So to save changing all existing page classes, I want to catch the use of ids and change to xpath in my waitForElement/doesElementExist methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method for waiting, it will return true/or false based on if the element was present during the polling time (10sec for example); worth noting that if the element is found as present earlier than the 10sec limit the loop will break and will return true. Of course you can play with timeOut to achieve the desired result; don't go to fast though (like 2 sec) otherwise you are risking your test occasionally failing because the tables were not loaded yet:

```
public boolean waitForElement(String elementXpath, int timeOut) {

try{                    
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut); 
boolean elementPresent=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(elementXpath)).isDisplayed());

System.out.printf("%nElement is present [T/F]..? ")+elementPresent;
}        
catch(TimeoutException e1){e1.printStackTrace();elementPresent=false;}          

    return elementPresent;   
 }
```